# Aspnetboilerplate: How to execute raw sql query

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

How to execute raw sql query in asp.net core aspnetboilerplate 5.6.0,
It seems entity framework code 3.1.4 is referred in the project

My code is as follows

```
public interface ISqlExecuter
{
    int Execute(string sql, params object[] parameters);
}

public class SqlExecuter : ISqlExecuter, ITransientDependency
{
    private readonly IDbContextProvider<InsProDbContext> _dbContextProvider;

    public SqlExecuter(IDbContextProvider<InsProDbContext> dbContextProvider)
    {
        _dbContextProvider = dbContextProvider;
    }

    public int Execute(string sql, params object[] parameters)
    {
        _dbContextProvider.GetDbContext().Database//<= Here I dont see any function to execute SQL query
        //return 0;
        //return _dbContextProvider.GetDbContext().Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, parameters);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They have provided the extension method `ExecuteSqlRaw`, you can call this method to run the query.

You can call like this.

```
dbContextProvider.GetDbContext().Database.ExecuteSqlRaw();
dbContextProvider.GetDbContext().Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync();
```